# TYPO3 can't access to root folder

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am new in TYPO3, I have a running system online and wanted to copy to my localhost, I copied the folder in /var/www/my_production/
I created the database, I can access to the backend without problem but I cant open my site, I get this error :

> ## 1323059807: You are not allowed to create directories in the folder "/" (More information)
>
> TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Exception\InsufficientFolderWritePermissionsException
> thrown in file
> /var/www/my_production/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/ResourceStorage.php
> in line 2021.

Any idea how I can fix that problem?

**EDIT ::**
After clearing the cache from the Install Tool, I got :
Fatal error: Call to undefined function

> TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\xml_parser_create() in
> /var/www/clevvermail_dev/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php
> on line 2252

[image]

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: and you have to check chmod of the folders

Comment: Have a look into the Installtool (BE modul install) and see 'Folder structure'

Comment: Clear the cache helped me to get rid of this problem but I saw now fatal error (See my update)

Comment: @jokumer : I get : Directory / is not writable
Path /var/www/my_folder exists, but no file underneath it can be created.

Comment: Means, Apache can not write at your localhost, its not a PHP or TYPO3 issue

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that XML is missing.

Try: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml` or `sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml`

Comment: it is installed

Answer (score 0):

First steps for each new TYPO3 installation: enter Install Tool and reduce all errors possible. (You might stay with some errors, but you need to understand them.)
TYPO3 gives a lot of hints what has to be changed.

typical errors:

- missing directories
- missing rights in directories
- wrong configuration in php.ini
- missing php modules
- database errors (connection, user, password)

try to solve these errors first.

Since TYPO7 you can check your extensions from the Install Tool.
For earlier versions:
disable all additional extensions (in PackagesState.php) and get the core working, then enable one extension after the other.